# What is the range of the mothership core's "Photon Overcharge"?

Tags: starcraft-2

The [new Photon Overcharge ability from the Mothership Core](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Mothership_Core) turns the Nexus into a cannon. What is the range of protection that this provides?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Starcraft wiki](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Mothership_core) and [Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Mothership_Core) the weapon has range 13, which is the same distance as a [Siege Tank](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Siege_Tank), targets air and ground and deals 20 damage.

The range of the Nexus means that no unit can easily attack while photon overcharge is active (60 seconds). Even tanks that have the same range, have 2 units less vision so need a spotter - this is also true of the Nexus - it has a range of 13 but sight of 11, according to http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Nexus

Comment: What is "range 13" mean in a practical sense? Does is cover all the workers? the mineral patches? beyond the mineral patches?

Comment: tanks have 12 IIRC, so just over siege tank range. Way more than collossus or BL. Almost twice as a cannon (cannons have 7). Over twice than a stalker (stalker have 6)

Comment: Tanks have range 13 in siege mode.

Comment: The Nexus can fire it's Photon Overcharge beyond the mineral line.